# Is there a way to run a Xamarin UWP project without deploying every time

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, uwp, windows-10-universal

Do I always have to click to deploy a UWP app before running it? Thats two steps and I'd like to perform just one.

I've just created a Blank Xaml App (Xamarin.Forms Portable) New Project from the list of Cross-Platform, Windows, Visual C# Templates in Visual Studio 2015 update 2. There are projects for Droid, iOS, and UWP (Universal Windows) as well as a few others. I set the UWP app as the startup project and attempted to run it (by clicking the green arrow on my local machine or hitting F5), but I received an error saying that I need to deploy first. If I right click the project and then choose deploy it deploys successfully and then if I run it runs successfully. If I stop execution, make modifications, then run again I do not see my changes. If I deploy again and then run I can see my changes.

I'm trying to just make sure my UI looks like it should and so anything that helps me iterate between making code changes and seeing those changes in any platform would be helpful. the Droid takes forever to start up and I can't run iOS (no Mac) or Windows 8.1 (I'm on windows 10 home) which is why I'm testing things out with UWP first. Is there a better way than right clicking the project to deploy every time before hitting run?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Goto Build menu ->select configuration manager goto UWP project select both build and deploy option .. it will automatically deploy default this option switch off

Comment: Awesome! I love when fixes are so simple. The other projects were set to do both, I just wonder how it was that the UWP project was not? Thanks.

Comment: I found this a little bizarre, my project used to do this and then suddenly I had to start deploying manually, not sure how this option got turned off. Assume when I got a VS2017 update