# The project "AppUIBasics" needs to be deployed before it can be started

Tags: uwp

I am a newbie to UWP and want to run a sample in the development environment.  I don't want to deploy yet.

I cloned 
https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlUIBasics

I built the project with 1 warning and now errors.

The warning was

```
0xdef00520 - Invalid qualifier: SCALE-100-WHITE
```

When I try to run it I get an error stating that the project needs to be deployed.
Verify the project is selected to be deployed in the Solution Configuration Manager, or deploy it explicitly by clicking one of the Deploy commands in the Build Menu.

[image: The project needs to be deployed]

I also see the following error in the error list

```
Error DEP0001: Unexpected Error: SmartDeviceException - 
The IP over USB Transport service (IpOverUsbSvc) is not available. 
Retry after installing the IP over USB Transport service
(Windows IP Over USB) through the Windows SDK installer. [0x80131500]   AppUIBasics
```

I am not sure if this is relevant but I see the references icons indicate they are in Azure devops ( in my experience )

[image: references]

In the Project Properties Application Tab I see the Target version is Build 17134 which is also the min version

I tried going into the Configuration Manager from the Build Menu and set Deploy unchecked.

[image: deploy is not checked]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37893335/is-there-a-way-to-run-a-xamarin-uwp-project-without-deploying-every-time?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it running by selecting x86 and Local Machine in the toolbar.
[image: as shown]